# Adding a user back to the database after destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and after creating a new user model, I was playing around with it in the rails console --sandbox.

I added 5 users to the database by 
    User.create

After doing this I deleted the first user

```
user1 = User.destroy(1)
```

Now I want to add user1 back to the database. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
User.create(user1.attributes)
```

With devise:

```
User.create(user1.attributes.merge(password: 'the_user_password'))
```

This work if you store the user destroyed at user1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you destroyed that one, so it's gone.

You can re-create the same user though if you know the attributes.

if the `user_id` was 1 you can do the following in rails console:

```
u = User.new(:id =>1)
u.save
```

Then you will see it when you type

```
User.all
```